# Adding intent filter into config.xml so that is inserted correctly in AndroidManifest.xml (Ionic 2)

Tags: android, cordova, android-intent, ionic2, phonegap

I want to use Android app links to link my app with my web site. I am having issues adding intent filters (correctly) so that they're written to the AndroidManifest.xml when adding Android platform. This is in a Cordova/Ionic app.

Any suggestions are highly appreciated :slight_smile:

Here is my intent filter:

```html
<intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
<action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
<data android:scheme="http" android:host="www.mydomain.com" />
<data android:scheme="https" android:host="www.mydomain.com" />
</intent-filter>
```

And how I was adding to add in config.xml

```html
<platform name="android">
<config-file target="AndroidManifest.xml" parent="./application/activity/[@android:name='MainActivity']">
<intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
<action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
<data android:scheme="http" android:host="www.mydomain.com" />
<data android:scheme="https" android:host="www.mydomain.com" />
</intent-filter> 
</config-file>
<config-file target="AndroidManifest.xml" parent="./" mode="add">
<application android:name="customApplication"></application>
</config-file>
</platform>
```

It did work with https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-custom-config plugin however the only way to insert it was the code below. It adds a second activity inside the Main Activity but it works fine.

```
<platform name="android">
    <config-file parent="application/activity" target="AndroidManifest.xml">
        <activity android:label="webIntentFilter" android:name="com.mydomain.myapp">
            <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:host="www.example.com" android:scheme="http" />
                <data android:host="www.example.com" android:scheme="https" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </config-file>
</platform>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have the correct syntax in your `<config-file>` block for intent-filters but unless you add the [cordova-custom-config](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-custom-config) plugin to your project, the `<config-file>` block won't do anything since Cordova CLI only supports `<config-file>` blocks in the `plugin.xml` of plugins (not `config.xml`).

Hence [cordova-custom-config](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-custom-config) is required to facilitate the application of custom config from within `config.xml`.

Once you've installed the plugin, your config should be applied to `AndroidManifest.xml` on the next Cordova `prepare` operation.

Note that the [example project for the plugin](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-custom-config-example) contains some examples of [custom intent filters](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-custom-config-example/blob/master/config.xml#L94).

You will need to set the application name attribute using a `<preference>` rather than `<config-file>`:

```
<preference name="android-manifest/application/@android:name" value="customApplication" />
```

Comment: Thanks. It's working but somehow the intent filter is being added twice in a row.